# error: invalid operands to binary << (have ‘struct str *’ and ‘int’)

Tags: c

How do I make sure that the following program does not cause these errors?

```
warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]    
warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]    
error: invalid operands to binary << (have ‘struct EXT_HDR *’ and ‘int’)
```

My expected output is: `15`

The code that does this is the following, where I'm using `typedef struct` pointer and #define (to get to know the usage).

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct EXT_HDR {
        int sar,rs;
}str;

#define output(O,I) (O |= ((str*)I->sar) | (((str*)I->rs)<<2))
int main(){

        int out = 0;
        str* val;
        val->sar = 3;
        val->rs = 3;
        output(out,val);
        printf("output= %d\n",out);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `EXT_HDR`? Where is that symbol defined? Please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: As for the error, perhaps you mean `(((str*) I)->rs) << 2)`?

Comment: What is this even supposed to do? The code makes no sense at all to me.

Comment: but what I want is I want to define bitwise operations using #define and i want to declare the variables I want to use in struct

Comment: without using the #define I can get the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to cast `int` to `str *`

```
((str*)I->rs)
```

Here you are casting `I->rs` to `str *` but you meant.

```
 ((str*)I)->rs
```

---

change

```
#define output(O,I) (O |= ((str*)I->sar) | (((str*)I->rs)<<2))
```

to

```
#define output(O,I) (O |= (((str*)I)->sar) | (((str*)I)->rs<<2))
```

Comment: but, when I used a normal assignment for that bitwise operation I didn't get an error is there any reason for that...

Comment: @SarathChandra The, why did you use casting in the macro?

Comment: actually, it is a part of a program I am working on. For fast operation, I'm using the macro - @manuell

Comment: @SarathChandra What do you mean by "fast operation"? Is that "typing fewer characters"?